# change/access the value of an array of checkbox in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I am trying to access my database and create a check box weather a transaction is still pending, Accept, Decline, Consume or paid. I had already access it through from database and print out in a check box. The problem now is I had a hard time in changing the values of the check box such as when the authorized user had approved a transaction (by checking the check box of the approved column), the pending check box would automatically unchecked and would automatically be saved. Same when a transaction would be declined.

Here is my code. Can anyone please help me in solving this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Pending Requests </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

session_start();

$myusername = $_SESSION['idNumber'];

if ($_SESSION['login'] == false) {
    echo "<script>alert('Login your account first');
            window.location.href='http://localhost/loginPage.php';</script>";
} else {
    session_start();
    $myBranch = $_SESSION['branch'];
    $myIdNumber = $_SESSION['id_number'];
    $username = "formtemplate";
    $password = "admin123";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("practice", $dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");

    $queryBranch = mysql_query("SELECT fname, lname FROM trial where department = '$myBranch'");
    $total2 = mysql_num_rows($queryBranch);

    $counter = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryBranch)) {
        $fname = $row['fname'];
        $lname = $row['lname'];
        $fullName[$counter] = $fname . " " . $lname;

        //echo "<option value = '".$fullName."'>".$fullName."</option>";
        $counter++;
    }

    echo '<form method = "post"> 
                    <select style="font-size:20px" name = "empList" length = "10">';

    //  echo "The first name is ". $fname;

    for ($a = 0; $a < $total2; $a++) {
        echo "<option value = '" . $fullName[$a] . "'>" . $fullName[$a] . "</option>";
    }
    echo '  </select>
                    <br><input type ="submit" name = "submit" value = "select">
                </form>';

    $fullnameHolder = $_POST['empList'];

    if ($_POST['submit'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        echo "You selected " . $fullnameHolder;
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t where name = '$fullnameHolder'");
        $total = mysql_num_rows($query);

        $counter = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

            //just add the all required data. This is only the practice
            $transNum[$counter] = $row['number'];
            $transactions[$counter] = $row['transaction'];
            $name[$counter] = $row['name'];
            $branchs[$counter] = $row['branch'];
            $dateIn[$counter] = $row['dateIn'];
            $dateOut[$counter] = $row['dateOut'];
            $pending[$counter] = $row['pending'];
            $approve[$counter] = $row['approve'];
            $decline[$counter] = $row['decline'];
            $consume[$counter] = $row['consume'];
            $paid[$counter] = $row['paid'];

            $counter++;
        }
        echo '<form method = "post">
                    <table border = "1">
                        <tr>
                            <th> Transaction number</th>
                            <th> Transaction</th>
                            <th> Name </th>
                            <th> Branch </th>
                            <th> Date From </th>
                            <th> Date to </th>
                            <th> Pending </th>
                            <th> Approve </th>
                            <th> Decline </th>
                            <th> Consume </th>
                            <th> Paid </th>

                        </tr>';
        for ($z = 0; $z < $total; $z++) {
            echo '<tr>
                                    <td>' . $transNum[$z] . ' </td>
                                    <td>' . $transactions[$z] . '</td>
                                    <td>' . $name[$z] . '</td>
                                    <td>' . $branchs[$z] . '</td>
                                    <td>' . $dateIn[$z] . '</td>
                                    <td>' . $dateOut[$z] . '</td>
                                    <td>' . '<input type="checkbox" name="sss[]" value="A"' . (($pending[$z] == "yes") ? "checked='checked'" : "") . '>' . '</td>
                                    <td>' . 
            '<input type="checkbox" name="ss" value="A"' . (($approve[$z] == "yes") ? "checked='checked'" : "") . '>' . '</td>
                                    <td>' . 
            '<input type="checkbox" name="ss" value="A"' . (($decline[$z] == "yes") ? "checked='checked'" : "") . '>' . '</td>
                                    <td>' . '<input type="checkbox" name="ss" value="A"' . (($consume[$z] == "yes") ? "checked='checked'" : "") . '>' . '</td>
                                    <td>' . '<input type="checkbox" name="ss" value="A"' . (($paid[$z] == "yes") ? "checked='checked'" : "") . '>' . '</td>


                                 </tr>';
        }
        echo '  </table>
                </form>';
    }
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It could be done with jQuery / javascript and ajax. I'd like to suggest you to put that if condition before your html output, and use `header('location: http://yourexample.com');` instead of javascript redirect. Also, use mysqli functions instead mysql functions, since, mysql functions are deprecated.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: On a separate note you don't need two session_start()

Comment: Thank you for the informations. I really have no idea that mysql is deprecated. I had already edited my code and used mysqli instead.

@lolka_bolka May I ask how can I compare my array of check boxes? Can I ask for some tutorials?